# How to kill the boss (Terra-tron) in Lost Viking

Tags: starcraft-2

Did anybody kill a "Boss" in "Lost Viking" arcade of StarCraft 2?

I saw the reward for gaining 125000 points in this game. How is it possible?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the boss name into the title, it's good for the question's visibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A boss? As in any of the 3 bosses? Mostly just dodge, learn their movements and their patterns and work around them. Setup a pattern that you follow to avoid their shots. To get GOLD achievement you have to defeat the 3 bosses I think 4-5 times. i.e you do all 3, then 3 again etc... (in the SAME game)

You can do it so you don't get hit from any of them, takes practice but it's very doable. Also do NOT hold down the fire key (space) a lot of people think it's easier to just hold it down and keep firing, but it's actually slower that way, if you want to go far in it you got to do it manually.

Comment: +1 for spamming spacebar rather than holding it down. *Now* I remember why I hated earning the Lost Viking achievements. My sore thumb :(

Answer (score 6):

Follow these instructions and you should have your Gold achievement fairly soon.

1. Get the items in the right order
2. Avoid dying by using bombs just before you get hit
3. Spam the spacebar
4. Save whenever possible (between fights). Especially on boss warning.

### Items

This is the right order:

- 2 x Missile Shot
- 2 x Drones
- Bombs

I usually use most of my bombs on Terratron.

### Saving

It is possible to save in Lost Viking just follow these instructions:

While playing (no pause) right click the Speaker Button and select *Voice Chat Options...*

[image]

Then the voice chat options menu appears. Press *ESC* or *Cancel* to get to the normal menu.

[image]

Here you can save as usual.

[image]

Comment: Wow, saving. Awesome.

Comment: Nice trick. It's quite easy without saving though.

Answer (score 4):

Practice makes perfect!

After defeating Terra-tron once you can either stop playing, or continue. Selecting continue means you start back on level 1 but with stronger/more enemies. As a matter of comparison, it took me approximately 8.5 levels before I reached "Gold", and it took about 50 minutes to get there.

Comment: Yep same sounds about right.